# Windows show/hide toggle control

Tags: c, windows, api, controls

I'm trying to create a window control where you can toggle the state from hidden to shown, that hides/shows some stuff when not hidden.
Something like this:

[image]

Is there any built in control to handle this? Or do I have to implement it myself?
And what would be the best method to implement something like this?

Thanks in advance..

(Also is there a name for this? I have no idea what to call it)

Comment: There is no built-in control for this. Not there's much value in one, since all the work is in the hiding and showing of auxiliary content, not the control itself. Create a control with a hide/show button. When the user clicks the button, hide/show the auxiliary content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to implement it yourself, but it's just a button with an icon on it that changes when you click it! Should be a breeze :-) Another way to do it is have 2 buttons in the same position and they hide one another when clicked - can be simpler to do.